# Photoshop Text Dipping In Line - Can't Fix

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text, creative-cloud

I'm having this problem with text in photoshop. On this line no matter what text or what font I use the text will dip in the middle. It can be seen between the 'X' and 'A' in 'example'

[image]

The strange thing is if I left justify the text. The dip remains in the same point of the document, seen in the below in between the E and X in'EXAMPLE4' - there's also another point in 'REFERENCE' on line two that has the same problem.

[image]

I can't properly articulate the problem so I haven't had any luck in googling for solutions.

Worth noting, it doesn't matter what font is used, in the example it's Trade Gothic LT Std Bold Condensed from Typekit, but any font will do this.

How can I fix this?

Comment: I have a feeling these example images are screenshots. What happens if you try to save the file in like jpg format and preview it outside of photoshop? It could be just a rendering bug. Various small and obscure bugs in Photoshop can be taken care of, by deleting the preferences. You could try that. You can do that by holding the following shortcut keys immediately after launching PS. WIndows: `Alt+Control+Shift` Mac : `Alt+Cmd+Shift`.'

Comment: Is the text line/box rotated? It looks like what happens when text is set on a slightly slanted line.

Comment: @Joonas - if we saved the file it also occurred.

Comment: @Mysterfxit - Check this already after some other sites point this out as a possible cause.

Comment: It seems extreme but removing all text from the document and starting again with new text boxes fixed the problem.

Comment: James, it is kinda extreme, but it's also not the smallest of errors to rotate it accidentally and then duplicate that around. What you could have also done, is draw a line along one of the long edges of a text layer from left to right, with the Ruler tool and check the angle value it gives. Then select all affected layers and use [this script](http://blog.kam88.com/en/transform-each-20.html). This is not the most reliable, as it relies on you drawing the ruler line spot on, but it should get you close enough to make it look normal again.

Comment: This is a good technique @Joonas - we're on CC here so when you rotate text boxes it gives you the angle. I made sure these were 0.0deg so I don't believe this was the issue however as creating new text boxes fixed the problem I can't rule it out

Comment: [I was able to recreate it, by ever so slightly using `Edit > Transform > Skew`, to move the right side downwards a bit.](http://i.stack.imgur.com/o848B.jpg). The text had to be relatively small ( 200% zoomed in the example image ), for this to occur. The smaller the text, the bigger the impact something like skew will have, with just a small small adjustment. I don't know if this was  the cause, but maybe.

Answer (score 1):

I found a quick fix by adjusting and using different anti-aliasing selections. "Sharp" appears to give me the same issue but if it is switched to "Strong" or "Crisp" the line is fixed